# Okta vs Azure AD B2C When Already Using Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, okta

I have an application that uses Azure AD to authenticate employees.  We now have a requirement to open up the app to external consumers.  We are strongly considering Okta to authenticate the external users and federating to Azure AD for the employees. I'm curious if it would be more advantageous to use Azure AD B2C instead of Okta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having been through this exercise, Okta is considerably more expensive.

You can federate B2C and Azure AD.

It depends on your use case i.e. what features are you looking for?

Comment: Right now we're just looking at the most basic features around getting user info synched out of Azure AD and implementing Role-based Access Control in the application with scopes, claims, and custom profile attributes.  My main concern is that the current web app is already using Azure AD for the internal employees.  I'm wondering if using Azure AD B2C will be easier to integrate into our app over Okta.

Comment: From development point of view it would be easier to use AAD and B2C since they share SDKs (MSAL, OWIN, Core Identity, etc.) and API: Microsoft Graph.

Comment: I am guessing you are using the MSAL library for the current web app? If so, the B2C MSAL library is very similar. Okta has it's own client library which is obviously different.

Answer (score 2):

Its important we understand what "external consumers" mean. They can be from a partner organisation or they can be end-users. Azure AD supports B2B and B2C mode and each one of them is different. Following are some of the design considerations

- Are the external consumers from partner organisation or end users?
- Does the application support integration with external IDp i.e gmail, facebook to name few.
- Licensing differs for both B2B and B2C

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/microsoft-cloud-it-architecture-resources#identity) documents the best practices to be used while making the decision

We have gone ahead with B2B because we already had Azure Premium License and that supported B2B licensing model. Feel free to analyze on your own.

On Okta, it is slightly more expensive as @nzpcmad says.

Comment: Just remember you only get 5 B2B licences per Azure AD licence. That may well push you to B2C. And B2C is a lot cheaper than Okta.

Comment: I am not sure how that will push to B2C. The B2B 1:5 ratio is beneficial in cases where your external users are more than the business users.

Comment: If you have 1000 internal and 100,000 customers you have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

For very basic scenarios, Azure B2C is both cheaper and easier to integrate into your existing environment. However, there is a large capability gap between the two offerings that becomes evident when you want particular features. Believe it or not, but Okta can actually be cheaper than Azure, especially if MFA is important with large user bases.

Azure charges for each MFA event, so:

```
MFA and SMS/Phone Events: $0.042
Auth: (50,000 MAUs x $0 (Free tier)) + (200,000 MAUs x $0.0076) = $   1,325 p/m
MFA:  250,000 MAUs x 2 (MFA Events per Month) x $0.042.         = $  21,000 p/m
Total:                                                          = $  22,325 p/m
                                                                = $ 267,900 p/a
```

- User Self-Service
- Session Management of Users
- Adaptive MFA (based on anomaly detection)
- User Activity Logging

Just make sure you compare apples to apples, and know what your actual technical and user requirements are.

Don't forget that there are cheaper alternatives to Okta, ie Auth0.